# Screenshot specific window in background without saving it as file

Tags: python

I would like to screenshot window in the background (not focused) without saving it as a file so it would be only as a variable. I have code that can screenshot the window but it will save it as .bmp. I can open it with pillow than but it would be better if it was saved in a variable instead of a file.
This is the code I use for the screenshot. I than open it with Image.open("imagename")

```
def background_screenshot(hwnd, width, height):
        wDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
        dcObj=win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(wDC)
        cDC=dcObj.CreateCompatibleDC()
        dataBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
        dataBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dcObj, width, height)
        cDC.SelectObject(dataBitMap)
        cDC.BitBlt((0,0), (width, height), dcObj, (0,0), win32con.SRCCOPY)
        dataBitMap.SaveBitmapFile(cDC, "images\\screenshot.bmp")
        dcObj.DeleteDC()
        cDC.DeleteDC()
        win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, wDC)
        win32gui.DeleteObject(dataBitMap.GetHandle())
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this, and replace the 'take screenshot' function with your.

```
import mss import mss.tools 
with mss.mss() as sct: # Use the 1st monitor
monitor = sct.monitors[1]
# Grab the picture 
im = sct.grab(monitor)
# From now, you have access to different attributes like `rgb`
# See https://python-mss.readthedocs.io/api.html
# mss.tools.ScreenShot.rgb 
# `im.rgb` contains bytes of the screen shot in RGB _but_ you will have to
# build the complete image because it does not set needed headers/structures
# for PNG, JPEG or any picture format.
# You can find the `to_png()` function that does this work for you,
# you can create your own, just take inspiration here:
# https://github.com/BoboTiG/python-mss/blob/master/mss/tools.py#L11
# If you would use that function, it is dead simple:
# args are (raw_data: bytes, (width, height): tuple, output: str)
Raw_bytes = mss.tools.to_png(im.rgb, im)
```

Or you can save the file and write a function that automatically deltes it after use.

```
os.remove(filepath)
```

Comment: This won't take a background screenshot, in fact; mss doesn't even support it.